# Deny public access to group in STASH/Bitbucket Server

Tags: permissions, bitbucket-server

In Stash/BitBucket Server, is it possible to, by default, deny access to all repos for a specific group/user?

We would then grant access to one or two repos to this person or group based on login status/permission assignment..

Our internal approach is:
- Many of our repos are public to those within our organization
- These repos should not be visible to external partners who closely work with us
- We want a close external partner to be able to see one or two repos.

We are using Atlassian Stash v2.12.1

Regards,
T

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, you have to discard public access to all repositories and projects, and grant access thanks to an "my-organisation" group in project permissions.

Then you can register per user permissions for specific repositories external partner has to access to.